# How to get MacBook Leopard installation disks?

Tags: leopard, install

We bought this computer second hand without the disks. Some of the applications were accidentally removed. The trash was emptied before realizing they were in there.

We are trying to find someone with the disks to recover what was lost.

Where to find the installation disks or if we can use other disks that are more available?

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't technically sell operating system software discs anymore. If you call AppleCare will often mail you replacement DVDs for what shipped with the system depending on how old it is (1-800-APL-CARE).

If you are looking for the DVDs for third party software **AND** you have the valid serial numbers for said programs, sometimes the software manufacturers will send you replacement DVDs.  That is as long as this system is the only one that they will be installed on.

Otherwise you can look on ebay/amazon for slightly out of date software that may well work for your needs.

If you need a very capable free office package you can try http://www.openoffice.org.  There are many very capable open source programs that you can use on the Mac as well: http://opensourcemac.org